# php pdo query not working with array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been doing this for quite a few queries but suddenly found one where it is not working. Here is my code:

```
$q = 'SELECT title FROM blog LIMIT :paging,:perpage';
$v = array(
    ':paging'=>(($page-1)*$perpage),
    ':perpage'=>$perpage
);
$sql = $conn->prepare($q);
$sql->execute($v);
if ($sql){
    foreach($sql as $rs){
        $title = $rs['title'];
        echo '<article>'.$title.'</article>';
    };
};
```

I am not getting any errors however It is also not displaying anything. When I take out $v and just put the values into the query like so:

```
$q = 'SELECT title FROM blog LIMIT '.(($page-1)*$perpage).','.$perpage.' ';
```

This works perfectly and outputs fields.

I have does this same array trick on many other queries in the past and never had any problems. Not sure what I did wrong here, need a fresh pair of eyes.

also $page = 1 and $perpage = 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because when you use an array for execute, it defaults to `PDO::PARAM_STR`, so it thinks its a string...which obviously doesn't play well with `LIMIT`

Instead use `bindValue`, that way you can explicitly state `PDO::PARAM_INT`

```
 $q = 'SELECT title FROM blog LIMIT :paging,:perpage';
 $sql = $conn->prepare($q);

 $sql->bindValue(':paging',(($page-1)*$perpage), PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sql->bindValue(':perpage',$perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sql->execute();
```

Comment: @MihaiStancu Your wrong, this answer is correct, `execute()` An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

Comment: They are not treated as string (nor would it matter if they are). They type is inspected and they are treated according to type.

Comment: Thanks bindParam almost worked, changed it to bindValue and that came through for me. Have to wait for time limit to accept this as the answer

Comment: @MihaiStancu from your link - `public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] ) :: input_parameters :: An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.` All values are treated as strings

Comment: Its not that yours worked or mine worked or whatever...its that I provided solid reasoning behind why his wasnt working, and some code...you didn't  :)  Effort pays off sometimes

Comment: Well would of but unfortunately effort isn't the issue... Mobile devices posting on here are as not able to post code!!

Comment: @KyleK my bad -- I distinctly remember reading that type inference is done there. Perhaps it happens in some other context.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use bindValues to bund the values to the query the use execute with no parameters!

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: Execute is meant to allow you to specify all bindvalues in one array;  http://php.net/manual/ro/pdostatement.execute.php; OP's code looks correct at first glance.

Comment: @MihaiStancu he didn't say you can't use an array - he just said that the OP forgot to bind the params

Comment: OP didn't forget... he used `->execute($v)`

Comment: @MihaiStancu he neither used `bind` nor sent the array to `execute`

Comment: +1 as technicality correct, though a simple example will encourage people to upvote.

Comment: Would but posted link as mobile wont allow you edit code correctly therefore won't allow you to post code

Comment: @alfasin From my first visit the array was being sent to `execute`. Perhaps OP edited his question and Liam saw OP's previous version.

Answer (score -1):

You're not getting any PHP errors but you're not checking for SQL errors at all. You need to explicitly check for SQL errors.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: downvoting without commenting (or as a childish "revenge") is lame!

Comment: My answer directs OP to investigate his SQL error and see for himself what the problem is. It's not an answer per se so I have no problem with their downvotes because it doesn't provide a solution.